# Can't get css file in node

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I just started learning Node.js and I have a small problem with getting data from css file. When I add data to the index file code it works.

Here are my codes:

**app.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

//404 response

function send404response(response) {
  response.writeHead(404, {
    "Context-Type": "text/plain"
  });
  response.write("Error 404: Page not found!");
  response.end();
}

function onRequest(request, response) {
  if (request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/') {
    response.writeHead(200, {
      "Context-Type": "text/html"
    });
    fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
  } else {
    send404response(response);
  }
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" >
    <title>First node app</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="container">Welcome to my first website! <br> This website is  created in NodeJs!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1voHP.png') repeat;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.container {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 90%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  padding: 5%;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1voHP.png') repeat;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.container {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 90%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  padding: 5%;
}
```

They are all in same folder.

Comment: Please condense blank lines where possible to make the questions more readable; also, consider trimming unnecessary content that isn't required for the question (such as the background colors, which are unlikely to be relevant)

Comment: "Context-Type" — It's spelt "Content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if( request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/' ){
>     response.writeHead(200, {"Context-Type": "text/html"});
>     fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
> ```

So if the browser asks for `/` then you'll send them the homepage…

> ```
> }else{
>     send404response(response);
> ```

… and if the browser asks for **anything else** you'll send a 404 error.

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" >
> ```

So when the browser asks for `/main.css` … you'll send a 404 error.

You need to write some code to actually handle the case of the browser asking for `/main.css`.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that out. Can you redirect me somewhere where I can learn more lot of nodeJs things I watched almost all videos and on theirs site I have how to get plugins like glup.js. i am very new. I saw one question for integrating node with php and answer was some basic chat app. Inside files all code was same as jqeury and socket io and node for server... So I am not following it very well... Thanks